# How to set Remember proxy login in Chrome

Tags: login, proxy, chrome

In Firefox we can remember login details for proxy authorization. How to do it in Chrome.

I have tried giving `chrome-proxy://proxy.company.com:port` which is suggested in  the Google forums, but it doesn't work. Can anybody please help, Chrome is always popping up for proxy logins.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to what I fought at my current place of work. I'm sure you've also found something like `--proxy-server=http://proxy.example.com:8080` for the desktop file. This works, but I do not believe you can set a login there.

A few suggestions:

1. Does your proxy use Active Directory logins? Install `cntlm` and
   configure it, and then configure chrome to use localhost:3128 when
   it's running.
2. Consider installing the foxyproxy plugin for chrome.
3. If it's a global proxy for a corporate environment and you have a
       supported desktop environment, you can probably set it similarly in
       the desktop environment settings and chrome will pick it up. GNOME
       shell has built-ins for this, however if I remember correctly, you
       need to use gconf-editor to get to the username and password bit.

Ultimately, I chose cntlm, since I can use it for my package manager (dnf on fedora), Firefox, and numerous other internet applications.

Comment: I was not able to install any third party softwares or add-ons to remember the proxy settobgs for chrome.